# Creating a list of tuples from a list

Tags: python

I had a list, for example:

```
data=['January', 'February', 'March',
      2007, 2008, 2009,
      'value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

Now I need to create the list of tuples in the following format

```
[('January', 2007,'value1'),('February', '2007','value2'),('March', 2007,'value3'),
('January', 2008,'value1'),('February', 2008,'value2'),('March', 2008,'value3'),
('January', 2009,'value1'),('February', 2009,'value2'),('March', 2009,'value3')]
```

Please let me know the concept

Comment: This is not valid Python, so I don't know what you want the list to look like exactly. Please fix that.

Comment: It is not good practice to call a variable `list` because you lose access to the builtin `list`.

Comment: @jamylak This appears to have been fixed and then reintroduced by editors - I'll edit back to using ``data``. I'm presuming the list of tuples was meant to have commas on line-ends as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions, as your question was a bit ambiguous about what you wanted, here are the solutions I would suggest.

Whatever you want, the first step is to split the list into independent lists. The cleanest way to do this is with a generator (there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312644/722121) of doing this for generators as opposed to lists, but for your use case that's overkill):

```
def segments(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n): #Use xrange in python 2.x
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

Although it's entirely possible to use a generator expression, it isn't particularly readable:

```
(data[y:y+3] for y in range(0, len(data), 3))
```

Wherever I use `segments(data, 3)`, you could use this generator expression instead, but I'll stick to the more readable version.

If you wanted output of matched `(month, year, value)`, then the answer is very simple:

```
list(zip(*segments(data, 3)) #No need to use list() in 2.x
```

Produces:

```
[('January', 2007, 'value1'), ('Febraury', 2008, 'value2'), ('March', 2009, 'value3')]
```

We unpack our three lists as arguments into `zip()` which gives us a generator of `(month, year, value)` items.

If you wanted all of the combinations of `(month, year, value)` then you can use `itertools.product()`:

```
from itertools import product
...
list(product(*segments(data, 3))
```

If you only wanted, as your output suggests, the set product of the month tied to the value and the year, then you will need:

```
from itertools import product
...
months, years, values = segments(data, 3)
[(month, year, value) for ((month, value), year) in product(zip(months, values), years)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
>>> l1 = ['January', 'February', 'March']
>>> l2 = [2007,2008,2009]
>>> l3 = ['value1','value2','value3']
>>> for year in l2:
...     print zip(l1, [year] * len(l1), l3)
...
[('January', 2007, 'value1'), ('February', 2007, 'value2'), ('March', 2007, 'value3')]
[('January', 2008, 'value1'), ('February', 2008, 'value2'), ('March', 2008, 'value3')]
[('January', 2009, 'value1'), ('February', 2009, 'value2'), ('March', 2009, 'value3')]
```

Splitting of the given list into tree pieces is left as an exercise for OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import product,cycle
>>> data = ['January','February','March', 2007,2008,2009,'value1','value2','value3']
>>> block = 3
>>> months,years,values = zip(*[iter(data)]*block)
>>> [(m,y,v) for (y,m),v in zip(product(years,months),cycle(values))]
[('January', 2007, 'value1'), ('February', 2007, 'value2'), ('March', 2007, 'value3'),
 ('January', 2008, 'value1'), ('February', 2008, 'value2'), ('March', 2008, 'value3'), 
 ('January', 2009, 'value1'), ('February', 2009, 'value2'), ('March', 2009, 'value3')]
```